# What if there is nothing to review?

Tags: discussion

The title is self explanatory. Let's say there is **the** perfect code in a question and the OP is asking for review. Is it bound to become a zombie? Should we say the question is perfect and ask the OP to delete it? Or maybe this never happens and I shouldn't care about this?

Comment: I was too late with adding a duplicate =/

Comment: I searched for such a question but couldn't find it -.-'

Comment: The main reason I was too late with adding a duplicate was that I had to search hard to find it.

Comment: I changed the question that this is marked as a duplicate of.